# github permission denied to push to my own repo

Tags: git, github, push

Recently I created an empty repos on github and cloned it to my laptop.  I wrote some stuff and wanted to push it to the github repos, so I committed locally then entered

```
git push origin master
```

That produced an error message:

> Fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.    An error occurred while
>   sending the request. Username for 'https://github.com': xxxxx
>   Password for 'https://xxxxx@github.com': remote: Permission to
>   xxxxx/yyyyy.git denied to xxxxx. fatal: unable to
>   access 'https://github.com/xxxxx/yyyyy.git/': The requested
>   URL returned error: 403

Where "xxxxx" is my username on github and yyyyy is my project (still empty!)

So, what am I missing?  What do I need to do to push to my own repos on github?

Comment: you have configured your proxy for a VPN?

Comment: @TalaatMagdy how is a VPN related in any way to github access?

Comment: @DavidMakogon  If have configured your proxy for a VPN, you need to login to your VPN to use the proxy

Comment: How did you authenticate to GitHub? Are you using [two-factor authentication](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/)?

Comment: Normally, I use TFA, yes. And...there is no VPN involved

Comment: The VPN question doesn't make much sense—I suspect Talaat meant "proxy". In any case, I guess you provided your password on the command-line?

Comment: Yes,  well actually, the CLI command pops up a dialog box.  I enter user id /password there and it fails, then falls back to the cli.  I do it again and get the error I posted.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using 2-factor authentication, you [need](https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/#through-the-command-line) to [set up a personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) to use instead of your password when pushing over HTTPS. In your account settings, go to **Developer settings** → **Personal access tokens** and generate a token with repo access, then use that instead of your password.

Alternatively, you can [set up an SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) and push over SSH, which I find more convenient.

Comment: Yeah, I used the token when I got the error.fwiw I just did it again and got the same error.  Copied the token from github, pasted it in when prompted. error

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried this, the popup gui prompted me for the code sent to my phone.  That solves the problem for now.